# Remove Duplicates Function not always working in Excel on Mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2016 on my Mac (v10.11) and currently working on a table for the accounting of my company. It contains two sheets: On the first sheet I list up some costs and give them a projectnr. These costs get copied and pasted on the second sheet. The projectnrs get copied in a protected column, where I need to delete all duplicates. I want to automate this process. if you click on a button on the first page, the rest of the game will be done by itself.
For this, I wrote a VBA function like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FirstTable").Range("R21:R84").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SecondTable").Cells(3, 26).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SecondTable").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SecondTable").Range("Z:Z").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FirstTable").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Call Print
End Sub
```

The problem is that the method RemoveDuplicates does not work on mac! I've tested it on windows and everything works well. Does anyone know what the reason for this could be?

If I mark the column on my own and click on remove duplicates in the data tab, it works, but not with this macro.

Comment: What if you use the macro recorder, on your Mac, to record yourself removing some duplicates. Then, it should generate code that you can tweak and use. Or, have you tried that, and the method just won't work?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/excel-2016-for-mac-vba-functions-remove-duplicates/220d5f98-03b4-431e-90f3-50ccfc56c0cd

Comment: @BruceWayne If I delete the duplicates by using the "Delete Duplicates" button in the data tab, the macro only records how I mark up the columns, but not how I delete the duplicates.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks! No i know that it's not my mistake.
What I'm looking for now is a function to delete all duplicates in a column and delete the empty cells as well. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it doesn't work:
On mac it pops up a dialog, which you need to confirm. If you don't hit the confirm button, the duplicates won't be removed. After I call the RemoveDuplicates function, I switch to the FirstTable by calling ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FirstTable").Activate. The dialog disappears and the duplicates are not deleted.
On windows there is no dialog, thats why it works.